# Angular 17 | Angular Material 17.3.1 Issue with styling Angular Material Menu component

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-material, angular17

I'm currently working with Angular 17 and Angular Material 17.3.1, and I'm encountering an issue with styling the Menu component. Specifically, I'm trying to adjust the height of the menu items, but my attempts haven't been successful so far.
Link -> https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples#menu-overview

Here's my sample code:

account.component.html

```
  <button
    class="btn btn-default"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="accountMenu"
    type="button"
  >
    <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #accountMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/register" type="button" class="menu-btn">
      Login
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
```

account.component.scss

```
  mat-menu {
    .mat-mdc-menu-panel {
      .mat-mdc-menu-content {
        button {
          min-height: 24px !important;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I've tried to adjust the height of the menu items using the provided Scss code, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Can anyone suggest what might be wrong with my approach or provide an alternative solution to style the menu items?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `::ng-deep` along with `:host` or you can add your css in `style.scss` so that you dont need to use `::ng-deep`.

```css
:host{
  ::ng-deep {
    mat-menu {
    .mat-mdc-menu-panel {
      .mat-mdc-menu-content {
        button {
          min-height: 24px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::ng-deep` directive

> The ::ng-deep CSS selector is often used in an Angular Component’s CSS to override the styles of a third-party component or a child component’s styles

Something just like this:

```
::ng-deep mat-menu > .mat-mdc-menu-panel > .mat-mdc-menu-content > button {
    min-height: 24px !important;
}
```

Comment: This workaround solution works on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the encapsulation strategy using **ViewEncapsulation.None**.

**Beware**:

> The styles of components are added to the  of the document,
> making them available throughout the application, so are completely
> global and affect any matching elements within the document.

To avoid that, you can include it in a component’css selector to define the css style:

**Exemple** :

// component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})....
```

// styles

```
my-app {
  mat-menu {
    .mat-mdc-menu-panel {
      .mat-mdc-menu-content {
        button {
          min-height: 24px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution you provided, although it's working, but it breaks the other components. I will stick with the ::ng-deep. Thanks!